# get item count on recyclerview not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I just like to know how to get the item count on my recyclerview and try this code but it is not working on me. Can you help me figure it out whats the problem on my code?

My Activity:

```
    public class NavDrawerFleet extends AppCompatActivity
            {
        private List<NavDrawerFleetGetterSetter> navList= new ArrayList<>();
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private NavDrawerFleetAdapter mAdapter;

            protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer_fleet);
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            Textview sucessCount=findViewById(R.id.success_count);
            recyclerView =findViewById(R.id.nav_sent);
            mAdapter = new NavDrawerFleetAdapter(navList);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
            LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            //item count in recyclerview 
            sucessCount.setText(String.valueOf(mAdapter.getItemCount()));
            }
         }
```

My XML:

```
               <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/success_count"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:text="00000"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="260dp">
               </Textview>
```

myConstructor

```
public class NavDrawerFleetGetterSetter {
String lat,lon,dateTime;

public NavDrawerFleetGetterSetter(String lat, String lon, String dateTime) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
}

public String getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(String lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public String getLon() {
    return lon;
}

public void setLon(String lon) {
    this.lon = lon;
}
enter code here
public String getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}

public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
}
```

}

these is my output:

[image]

if you notice, the failed sent was not counting the cardview data on my recyclerview.

Comment: Please add adapter's code also

Comment: Where are you populating the navList variable?

Comment: ow sorry, i forgotted, just got editen.. on my recyclerview, my data was fetched but the count item was not working.

Answer (score 0):

From Recyclerview.Adapters Android Documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#getitemcount) getItemCount() counts the total number of items in the dataset held by the adapter.

As I cannot see any item added to your newly created navList in your code getItemCount() seems to be rightfully zero. You have to add items to the list for them to be counted!

Comment: sorry, i didn't add the other details. I just got updated my question for you :)